# access value inside annotation in php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, annotations, router

how can i access string "/about" inside Route class in my custom code like symfony and laravel do?

for example in class bellow i want my code to get route and pass it to my Route supper class to render the page

```
class AboutPage {
    #[Route('/about')]
    public function page() {}
}
```

should i read files like text files and generate an json or xml based on annotations or is there and built-in option ?

i tried to get the passed string inside Route class __construct($path) method, but it did not work